# Android Open Source contains the linux source code also?

Tags: android, embedded-linux

My question is if Android open source project does have a linux kernel source code along with AOSP tree? or if i want to build android on different embedded device, do i need to build linux separately?

Kindly advice?

Answer (score 0):

The Android project contains sources for the Linux kernel with support for several well-known boards (devices.)   Although probably not an exhaustive list, this link details those boards and the default configurations (defconfigs) used to build them. http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html

If you want to build Android on your own custom embedded device, you will very likely have to modify (port) Linux to your particular device, including the creation of a default configuration used to build.  You should start with a configuration that is close to your own custom device to minimize your work.  You don't necessarily have to build Linux separately, although it might be more convenient to do so for development purposes.  That depends on your own development environment and style. It shouldn't be difficult to modify the build system to incorporate your kernel changes, but you're probably on your own if you wish to do so.